# How do I trim arched windows?

Tags: windows, trim

I have two arched windows, a small one and a large one. I have no idea how to trim the windows. I know how to trim a normal window, but the arches are very different. I've searched online and all of the videos/articles are terrible and provide very little insight in the materials and methods.

What material can I use to build the interior jamb and the outside trim? I'm going for something very basic and craftsman. I'd prefer to just have a pine arched board, but can't find anything like that at box stores.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the trim going to be painted or stained/clear coated? I have made that type of trim, but one way is much simpler than the other.

Comment: @Jack It will be painted white.

Comment: Arched trim (or "arched casings") are widely available - search with those words and you'll find what you need.  You need to get the right radius to match your openings.

Comment: Good thing is most of these are further away from the viewer, being "socially distanced" suggests you have options - it just has to look good from a distance.

Answer (score 5):

One way it could be done is wrap it all in drywall and corner bead. I feel that is really cheating for when it is trimmed out properly it is really stunning.

To add jamb extensions to the window jambs that are there already for the side are really straight forward. Add 1X shimmed so the finished face is 1/4" behind the face of the window jamb to create a "reveal". If you are trimming the window "picture frame" style having mitered corners at the bottom, instead of a more traditional sill/stool with apron the bottom is treated the same as well. BUT only after you set the curved head first using PVC 1X that is readily available at practically and lumber store. When cut to the right length and sprung into place, it will practically bow itself into the arch you need. Set the curve with shims to keep the curve faired in with the window jamb and screw in palace to keep it secure. Nails do not hold well in PVC and a few well filled screw holes will disappear after paint.

The curved trim you will find available at you local big box stores. [Link here for HDs "Flextrim"](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Flex-Trim-HD-1x4-3-4-in-x-3-1-2-in-x-144-in-Polyurethane-Flexible-Flat-Stock-S4S-Moulding-90131/202961509) It won't be cheap. It will bend to the larger radius you have, but you may need to get the tighter radius custom poured. [Link here for custom made flexible trim](https://www.trimster.com/catalogs/browse/Flexible_Flat_Stock/popular)
The last link even has a formula for figuring you radius'

Comment: The way I would prefer to make the trim is to figure the radius exactly, draw the trim dimension to its finished size, make a segmented arc covering the lines drawn that is biscuited and glued, make a trammel and attach it to my router with a 1/4" straight cutting bit, and cut it out of wood. Since I seen a comment from the OP that it would be a lot to do, doing a similar suggestion, the only way it would get easier is to use bendable trim. But that will only do large radiuses. The smaller radius may need to be custom made. That is done by pouring the material in pre-bent silicone molds.

Answer (score 4):

You have to cut multiple pieces of the desired width for the wall trim at an angle when all of them reach 180 degrees combined. Probably about 6" - 8" each. Biscuit join them and glue the assembly up....probably straps would be best with a spreader across the bottom.   Then, using a template  you carefully created from cardboard of the window opening, transfer it to the glued up assembly via pencil to the assembly after a day of drying. If you have access to a band saw, cut close to the line and sand down the difference.  It's not critical you get to exact dimensions for the wall trim.   For the wrap inside, it is critical. But it's mostly the same process, biscuit joints with slight angles on each piece to make 180 degrees, with the exception that the cuts will be obviously along the wide part of the trim.

You'll need enough material to trim after gluing and sanding to get the finished look you want.     I've done this, it's an arduous task.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This seems like a reasonable approach but I don't want to do that much work :( Seems like I'm going to have to though. I'm surprised box stores don't have any arched molding.

Comment: Arched windows are probably less common than you'd think, @GaryHoliday, and they come in different sizes - they'd have to stock pre-made arches in such a wide variety of sizes that they'd probably only sell 1 or 2 of each size a year. That's a lot of inventory sitting on the shelf just to make your life easier for one day.

Comment: They do have arched molding its a very flexible molding i used it on my arched windows.

Comment: Given the OPs later comment it would just be painted white, I take back my answer and support other's answers.  I assumed the OP wanted a real wood look, based on the windows and the T&G ceiling. My bad.   But nobody and I mean nobody knows more about curved trim than me, I'm an expert anybody who tells you different is fake news.  

OK, that last sentence is just for fun, I'll probably get snipped by a moderator for it, but it was too fun to resist.

Answer (score 3):

"I'm going for something very basic and craftsman". If by "craftsman" you mean Craftsman Style as promoted by Gustav Stickley in the early 20th century, then A) arches don't really play in as Craftsman Style is predominantly straight lines, but B) your trim will likely be wide, flat and simple.

If you're going for a simple, flat trim around the window *and* you're painting it, you can simply cut the arch trim out of a piece of plywood of the appropriate thickness to match up with the vertical trim for the rest of the window.

You'll want to use a nice grade of plywood, preferably without voids, so you don't end up with holes in the edges. I wouldn't bother with a hardwood plywood like oak or maple - while this is extremely high quality, you won't see it because you're painting it, and it'll be money wasted on a great surface that will be hidden behind paint

Determine the radius of the arch, then mark it out on a piece of plywood. Determine the width of your trim and draw a new line on the plywood. A simple piece of string tied around a nail at the center of the arch circle, with a pencil held or tied at the appropriate radii for the inner and outer edges of the arch will do the trick to make a nice smooth arch.

Once you've got it marked out, cut it out on a bandsaw or with a jig saw, staying just outside the lines, then sand right up to the lines for a nice, smooth finish.

Apply your plywood trim to the wall, match it up with the rest of the trim, and you're done.

For the interior jamb, I'd second [Jack's suggestion](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/242646/34147) of using PVC trim. It's quite flexible and should conform to the curve quite nicely. I purchased a 4x8' sheet of it a couple of summers ago for some trim work on my porch. It's easy to work with standard wood working tools, it's flexible, so it will conform to the inside curve, and the little trim-head screws & plugs will make the fasteners almost invisible.

One *drawback* to using it is that the surface finish is different than wood and may well be pretty obvious under the direct sunlight coming in the window. You could get textured-to-look-like-wood PVC boards, and they'd look closer, but the texturing on them is fairly aggressive for an interior finish. The other drawback to PVC is that it's not really designed to take paint, so if you're not planning on gloss white, it may be difficult to get the paint to match up.

To use wood, cut another strip of your plywood (or solid wood to match the rest of the jamb, if you desire) to the width of the jamb and long enough to make the inside radius of the arch, then set your circular saw to about 3/4 of the thickness of the plywood. Make cuts along the plywood's short dimension, about every inch. By putting the cut side up, you should have enough flexibility in the plywood to conform to the arch shape, while still having enough strength for it to remain in one piece. Once this jamb piece is in place, you'll have a bit of the cut piece exposed, but you can cover it with your wall trim.